# Convert Forever Changing Randomly Generated Integers Into Strings

Tags: java

[Solved]

I've searched many forums as well as Stack Overflow's questions for converting an ever changing random number to a string but I couldn't find a solution to my specific problem.

How do I go about converting customerID to a string?

```
    public class UniqueCustomerNumber {

    private int customerID;

    public void setCustNum(int cNumber) {
        Random x = new Random();
        cNumber = x.nextInt(800000001) + 100000000;
        customerID = cNumber;
    }

    public int getCustNum() {
        return customerID;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "as a string that doesn't change"? Your question is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I edited the question. I need to convert customerID to a string.

Comment: If you reuse a single [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), you'll get a better random sequence. By creating a new one each time, you're generating a new seed which limits you to the randomness of seed generation. You can use [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random\(\)) to avoid managing your own instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Integer.toString(int i)` It's a static method in `Integer` class that takes one `int` as an agument and returns its textual representation as `String`.

```
public class UniqueCustomerNumber {

    private String customerID;

    public void setCustNum() {
        Random x = new Random();
        this.customerID = Integer.toString(x.nextInt(800000001) + 100000000);
    }

    public String getCustNum() {
        return this.customerID;
    }
}
```

---

Code:

public class UniqueCustomerNumberTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UniqueCustomerNumber uin = new UniqueCustomerNumber();
    uin.setCustNum();
    System.out.println("Unique Customer Number = " + uin.getCustNum());
}
```

Output:

```
Unique Customer Number = 748816502
```

A side note: Using this method may not be in compliance with your class name, `UniqueCustomerNumber`. I know that the probability is really small, but it could theoretically happen that 2 customers have the same IDs if you generate them this way. A much simpler approach is to start assigning cutomers their IDs starting from some number, 1, for example.

On each assignment, you'd increase your counter by 1. The downside is that you'd need to keep that counter saved somewhere (DB, txt file, w/e).

Comment: Can you post your FULL code? You say it's returning null. Have you tried calling the setter in the 1st place?

Comment: @UgochukwutubelumChiemenam - It's a bit much to expect people to read that much code. [`Integer.toString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString\(int\)) is definitely what you want. You must have some other error to track down.

Comment: I'm sorry, but skimming through your code, I cannot find such a place for null value.  Re-read my answer (I added some new stuff) and try to use Debug mode in Eclipse. All I know is that the solution I provided works :D

Comment: That is why I trimmed the code in the first place. I have way too much code for a quick answer. You're right Integer.toString(int i) worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! All your solutions that you proposed worked!

Comment: @Lopina So I accepted (green-ticked) your answer. Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it...

**1. Concatenate** it to a String (can be an empty string).

**eg:**

```
int i =  5;
String s = i + "" ;    // i is now converted to String.
```

**2.** Use the **toString() method**, but this **works only with Object type**. So first you need to convert the primitive type int to Wrapper object Integer

**eg:**

```
   int i = 5;
   Integer o = new Integer(i);
   o.toString() ;
```

Comment: [`parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) parses an `int` from a given `String`. `int x = Integer.parseInt("123");`

Comment: @Thanks david, by mistake instead of writing toString i wrote parse, thanks for pointing it out..i have edited it now. Thanks once again

Comment: This will work, but Lopina's answer is preferable. There's no need to create a `StringBuilder` (string concatenation) or `Integer` instance to format a number as a string.

Comment: Yes the  is no need to, i just gave the ways to do it.... I think there is lot of misunderstand understand the points... I think you missed the very first sentence of the answer. "Two ways to do it", before downvoting something, read the entire content

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer; in fact no one has yet. I only said that Lopina's answer is preferable in this case and gave my reasoning.